# Can we have a refresh link in the "This question is now closed" message?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, live-refresh

Am I so lazy to ask if we could have a *link* to refresh the page in this message?

[image]

Something like:

[image]

I've seen this message for the first time and was looking for a way to actually refresh the page. Do you think we could have some way to refresh the page from the message itself?

Comment: Does your browser not have a refresh button? Seems like that would be present on any page.

Comment: @sphanley, it does. Even my keyboard has CTRL and R buttons (yet). I'm just feeling this message is not fully utilized.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. But for whatever it's worth my personal opinion is that it's unnecessary to create a UI feature to duplicate something that can already be done so many other ways.

Comment: Press `F5`, works like a charm :-)

Comment: @Kevin, that is still difficult when you're holding mouse in your right hand and a cup of coffee in the other hand :)

Comment: @TLama haha fair enough, maybe invest a little in technology so you can wink to refresh? Just joking around ^^

Comment: +1, If the "click here to refresh the page" message after the auto-login has a link, then I don't see why this can't have one.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I was actually against this before I saw this comment, now I've been won over! If it's a simple job for the devs it seems worth introducing for consistency's sake, if nothing else.

Comment: On my FF, rt-click pops up a context-menu with a 'refresh' icon on it.   No need to put coffee down or scroll up to the icon on the url bar.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why there has to be a refresh button, or popup at all. If the page is smart enough to know there was a change, it should be smart enough to update the respective part of itself just as well. Of course, after that you can pop up a small dialog notifying the user that there was a change and that the page had updated itself.

Comment: @carlspring: There is no answer form on closed questions, so automatically refreshing the page might cause the answer to be lost. Also, generally it's a bad idea for a page to be automatically refreshed, as it can cause the current context to be lost. Stack Exchange has solved this in an ideal manner - it provides notifications of changes, and a link to refresh. This should be no exception.

Answer (score 47):

This type of link is already active on other areas of the site. Most notably, it occurs when you return to a site and aren't logged in initially.

[image: Refresh]

I feel this type of link should be do able for the "Now Closed" message as well.